# How to save parentId with value 0? object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a SQL **table - table_description** with three columns.

1) ID - identity and primary key

2) Description

3) Parent_Id - this links back to ID in the SAME table.

There is a record with `ID = 0` as one of the rows. When I try to create a new record with `Parent_Id = 0`, NHibernate throws me error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to
>   something that would make it autosave

I am guessing this is because when NHibernate tries to generate a new record, it looks if the `ID =0` and since it sees `parent_Id = 0`, it thinks that there is a dependency.

This being understood, **how do we create a new record with `parent_Id = 0`**?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try to set your [ID's unsaved-value](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id) property to some value that does not exist in your table, i.e. **-1**. The default for integer columns is **0**.

You can change it like this in fluent mapping class:

```
Id(x => x.ID).UnsavedValue(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I actually figure out a workaround by just getting the parent record from the DB and assigned that to the ParentId instead of doing `parentId = new Descrption {id =0} `.